# Prove that the rational parametrized map $\mathbf{A}^1\rightarrow \mathbf{A}^3$ is continuous in the sense of Zariski topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

> Prove that the rational parametrized map 
>   $$\mathbf{A}^1\rightarrow \mathbf{A}^3 : t\mapsto (t^3,t^4,t^5)$$ is continuous in the sense of Zariski topology.

I am trying to prove the curve $$C:\{(t^3,t^4,t^5);t\in \mathbf{A}^1\}$$
is one-dimensional. It is natural to consider the map
$$\phi: \mathbf{A}^1\rightarrow \mathbf{A}^3 : t\mapsto (t^3,t^4,t^5)$$
If $\phi$ is a homeomorphism between $\mathbf{A}^1$ and $\phi(\mathbf{A}^1)$, then $C$ is one dimensional. However, it is easy to show $\phi$ is injective.

Now the rest of proof is to show $\phi$ is a continuous map (it is easy to show that $\phi$ is a closed mapping).

However, I got stuck here: how to prove if $\phi^{-1}(W)$ is infinite then $\phi^{-1}(W)=\mathbf{A}^1$.

Comment: Polynomial maps are continuous.

Comment: @Mohan But we are doing this on Zariski topology. I think this is not obvious to be true.

Comment: @Mohan I am stupid. Now I know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you got it, but for future possible lurkers: let $Z \subset \mathbb{A}^3$ be an algebraic set defined by $(f_1, \dots, f_r)$. Then $\phi^{-1}(Z)$ is defined by the equations
$$F_i(t) = f_i(t^3, t^4, t^5).$$
It is trivial to generalize this to polynomial maps.